# comparison of the two tables line by line

Tags: bash, scripts

I need to compare one - second column on two tables line by line.
Tables:
`1.csv`

```
1a  2
14  4g
```

`2.csv`

```
1a  2
1  4
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
text1=$(cat "1.csv" | awk '{print $2}')
text2=$(cat "2.csv" | awk '{print $2}')

if [[ "$text1" == "$text2" ]]
then
echo "true"
else
echo "false"
fi
```

But I get only one result - false.

Why I get only one result - false? must be true (2=2) false (4g!=4)

Comment: Whats your desired output?

Comment: Hello heemay|
I want output by line
true  (because 2 = 2)
false  (because 4g != 4)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
paste 1.csv 2.csv | awk '$2 == $4 {print "true"; next} {print "false"}'
```

Example:

```
$ paste 1.csv .csv | awk '$2 == $4 {print "true"; next} {print "false"}'
true
false
```

The `paste` command combines lines from the files provided to it, so I get line ` of the first file and line 1 of the second file in the first line of output and so on:

```
$ paste f1 f2
1a  2   1a  2
14  4g  1  4
```

This lets you directly compare the fields in `awk`, which can then print the desired string.

The `next` command in `awk` skips to the next line without processing further commands, so I don't need to write the `$2 != $4` condition  for the second block.

Comment: muru,
but in this case I create unnecessary table=(

Comment: @Oleksii what do you mean?

Comment: Why I need copy/paste second table to first, if I want only compare column on it?)

Comment: You don't need to, the `paste` command will do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$2; next}; a[FNR]==$2 {print "true"; next} \
                                            {print "false"}' f1.csv f2.csv
```

- `{a[NR]=$2; next}` will be executed only for the first file, `f1.csv`, an array `a` will be created with key as line number, and value as corresponding value of second field for the record
- `a[FNR]==$2 {print "true"; next} {print "false"}` checks if the value from array `a` for corresponding line number from `f2.txt` is equal to it's second field, if so `true` is printed else `false` is printed

**Example:**

```
% cat f1.csv 
1a  2
14  4g

% cat f2.csv                                                                                                                  
1a  2
1  4

% awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$2; next}; a[FNR]==$2 {print "true"; next} {print "false"}' f1.csv f2.csv  
true
false
```

Comment: `for (i in a)` might screw up the order, I think you can do the comparison and printing instead of the `b[++j]=$2` part.

Comment: @muru indeed, check now.

Comment: heemayl, thank you!
Work=)
guys,and as how the output of the commands written in the $3 column?=)
me recommended to to do

Comment: me recommended compare colums by
{if ($3 == $4) {print "true"} else {print "false"}}
but this variant not work=(

Comment: @Oleksii I'm finding its hard to understand what you are meaning. Could you please be a bit clearer.

Comment: Heemay|,
Thank you! Your variant works.
To me have recommended using the command for compare column:

Comment: {if ($3 == $4) {print "true"} else {print "false"}} 
but this variant not work.

Comment: how I can write the output of the commands:
true
false
into $3 column 1.csv file?
if I use >> 1.csv,  write to first column.