# add column and save file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

How I can add column and overwrite .csv table

Command:

```
$ paste -d ' ' 1.csv <(cut -d ' ' -f1 status.csv)

$ cat 1.csv
1  2
2  5

$ cat status.csv
true
false
```

If I use `> 1.csv` - deleted all columns in file 1.csv and save only first column from file status.csv
I want add first column from file status.csv to file 1.csv and save file 1.csv with new column from from file status.csv?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the closest you are going to get is to use the `sponge` utility from the `moreutils` package

```
DESCRIPTION
       sponge reads standard input and writes it out to the specified file.
       Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input before writing
       the output file. This allows constructing pipelines that read from and
       write to the same file.
```

So

```
paste -d ' ' 1.csv status.csv | sponge 1.csv
```

If you are asking this as a follow-on to your previous question [comparison of the two tables line by line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837875/comparison-of-the-two-tables-line-by-line), then you could eliminate the intermediate `status.csv` file for example by doing

```
paste 1.csv 2.csv | awk '{print $1, $2, $2 == $4 ? "true" : "false"}' | sponge 1.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sort](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/sort.1.html), with the `unique` flag
Like this:

```
paste -d ' ' 1.csv <(cut -d ' ' -f1 status.csv) | sort -uo 1.csv
```

---

```
-u, --unique
    with -c, check for strict ordering; without -c, output only  the
    first of an equal run

-o, --output=FILE
    write result to FILE instead of standard output
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to do it in a single operation, if possible.